# Blacklist /dev/sdo

Tags: linux, centos, disk

I have a computer with an SD card slot without any card in it which by default linked to the `/dev/sdo` name.
Since no SD card was inserted no block device is shown while viewing `lsblk` output, therefore I can only see the slot when executing `/dev/disk/by-path(/id)` under SD CARD etc...

If I disable the SD card through BIOS, the entire system's disk order is changing.

My question is how can I blacklist the name `/dev/sdo` entirely after disabling the sd card slot?
This means the OS will never show `sdo` name.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can. There's hundreds of devices in Linux that you can, in general not just access successfully without something else being fulfilled. Why is /dev/sdo special? Also, does orders of disks really matter? For what? You usually address disks and disk volumes through UUIDs.

Comment: *My question is how can I blacklist the name /dev/sdo entirely after disabling the sd card slot? This means the OS will never show sdo name.* I still don't understand it, but probably a `udev` rule is what you're looking for.

Comment: "which by default linked to the `/dev/sdo` name" – I wouldn't say it's "by default", it's rather "by chance" that happens to repeat; but it's not guaranteed to repeat. Stop relying on names like `sda`, `sdo`. If you do this properly then the fact "the entire system's disk order is changing" won't matter. If such change happened in my Linux, I wouldn't even notice (so maybe it did change and I didn't notice).

Comment: Hi,
 I have vgs and lvs with a name of same name of the block device attached to.
that's why I have now "sdd" disk with vg  & lv named "sde", where it should be the same scheme, "sdd" disk with vg & lv named "sdd".

Comment: Your "sdd" LV now has the "wrong" name because you *chose* to base its name on a device name that is explicitly documented as being subject to change on reboot for any reason (or no particular reason at all), ignoring all the documentation and advice that warns you against doing this. Reasons for a drive name changing include (but are not limited to): drive added, drive removed, drive moved from one slot/port to another, kernel module load order, new kernel version, minor changes in timing during boot or HW detection, updated BIOS, changes to BIOS config

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the replay,
The disk order changed and drift by one letter after installing a driver.
Is there any possibilty to make sure this wont change the disk drift issue?

Comment: No, not possible.  As has been said several times, /dev/sdX device names (i.e. drive letters) are not guaranteed to remain the same across reboots. Don't use them.  Use UUIDs or LABELs instead, they are guaranteed to remain consistent - that's why they exist.